# Are these two snippets equivalent?

Tags: swift, appdelegate, nsapplication

Are both of this snippets the same? Is it possible that on the first one myClass can at some point in the lifetime of the application will be eliminated?

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    private let myClass = MyClass()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        myClass.doSomething()

    }
}
```

and

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    private var myClass: MyClass?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        myClass = MyClass()
        myClass?.doSomething()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the two snippets are not equivalent. You can not reassign a `let` in Swift. In your second snippet the line:

```
private let myClass: MyClass?
```

should be:

```
private var myClass: MyClass?
```

Assuming that your two snippets don't include any other code that could interact with the variable then it would be the same.

Comment: That was a typo, now that i corrected that mistake are they both the same?

Comment: Assuming that your two snippets don't include any other code that could interact with the variable then it would be the same.